# Heap-Dynamic or Stack-Dynamic?

Tags: heap-memory, programming-languages, callstack

Please explain to me if "x" is a Stack-Dynamic variable or Heap-Dynamic variable in this code?And if it is Heap-Dynamic then why it is not Stack-Dynamic variable?Thank you

```
function foo(){ MyClass x = new MyClass();}
```

Comment: If this is homework: what do you think the answer is, and why?

Comment: no this not homework.I couldn't come up with a better example to present my confusion.

Answer (score 8):

**Stack dynamic** variables come into existence when you call a function. They exist on the C++ runtime stack, and are temporary. They are either in the parameter list, or declared inside the function (except for statics, which are not instantiated on the stack). These variables disappear when they go out of scope, and the memory for their contents is reclaimed by the runtime.

**Heap dynamic** instances exist in another area of memory the runtime sets aside called the "heap." These instances come into being via. the "new" operator, and must be explicitly deallocated by the "delete" operator.

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what language this is, I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's merely pseudo code, but the concepts should be the same across most of the common OO languages.

Let's break this down:

```
function foo() {
    MyClass x = null;
    x = new MyClass();
}
```

The first line `MyClass x = null` will allocate some space on the local stack. It's not a lot of space, just enough to store a reference.

The second line `x = new MyClass()` will do a few things:

1. Allocate space on the heap for a new instance of MyClass
2. Call the correct constructor for `MyClass`
3. Change the `x` reference to point to this new instance.

So the simple answer is: it's both.

Comment: Note that a declaration like `MyClass x` is not necessarily just a reference in every language.

Comment: so how does a compiler decides if a variable should be allocated on stack or heap?.Is the "new" keyword the trigger here?or is there a more general rule?.This is Because if instead of "MyClass x" if it had been "int x",then that would be a stack-dynamic variable.right?

Comment: precisely. Heap allocation is almost always explicit using `new`, `malloc`, or something similar.

Comment: So what if "MyClass" contains instance variables that are primitives like "int y".Are these also Heap-Dynamic then because "MyClass" is?

Comment: That's an excellent question, and you're absolutely right. In that case it would be allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

This specific one is: Dynamic-Heap (I'm assuming you're programming in JAVA here). As to why it's not on the stack?

- This allocates memory
- It's not an automatic variable

See this article for general directions:
http://www.maxi-pedia.com/what+is+heap+and+stack

Comment: Why are you assigning malloc'd memory to a plain old char? Also what is `calcSize`?

Comment: ok. Is this variable's space going to be allocated at runtime or compile time?

Comment: Runtime, only primitive types and String (with final) are compile time. private final int number = 10; can be Compile time for example

Comment: So it is the keywords that decide whether to declare a variable as Stack-Dynamic or Heap-Dynamic?E.g. "int x=2" is Stack-Dynamic because of "int" and MyClass x=new MyClass() is Heap-Dynamic because of "new".